# python: Ignoring first key in a dict for each row in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am working with a pandas dataframe that includes a dict as a field. The first level key is always uniquely named, and I would like to iterate past it to pull out a nested value and append it to a list. Here's an idea of what the dicts looks like:

```
{
    'alpha': {
        'date': 'April 18th, 2020',
        'name': 'Steve'
        'countries': [
            'Grenada',
            'Liechtenstein',
        ],
    }
    'sigma': {
        'date': 'March 13th, 2020',
        'name': 'Storm'
        'countries': [
            'Mayotte',
            'Palau',
            'Bhutan'
        ],
    }
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is grab anything in the "countries" keys and append it to a list (and add that to a new column in the dataframe). For this specific dict, the list I would like to gather would look like **['Grenada','Liechtenstein','Mayotte','Palau','Bhutan']**

Comment: store your dictionary in a variable named data and then `result=pd.DataFrame(data).loc['countries'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like

```
my_list = []
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    my_list += v['countries']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the dict, to get the desired output:
example:

```
dict_list= {
    'alpha': {
        'date': 'April 18th, 2020',
        'name': 'Steve',
        'countries': [
            'Grenada',
            'Liechtenstein',
        ],
    },
    'sigma': {
        'date': 'March 13th, 2020',
        'name': 'Storm',
        'countries': [
            'Mayotte',
            'Palau',
            'Bhutan'
        ],
    }
}
my_list = []
for i,v in enumerate(dict_list):
    my_list.extend(dict_list[v]['countries'])
print(my_list)#['Grenada', 'Liechtenstein', 'Mayotte', 'Palau', 'Bhutan']
```